# Running an exe application from local resource inside ASP .Net Core HTML page

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, asp.net-core, winforms-to-web

My software is splitted into 2 parts:

1. ASP .Net Core 3.1 application which is hosted on server
2. .NET Framework 4.8 WinForms applicaнion which is deployed on client PC (I can try to place it on server if this greatly simplifies the solution of the problem). The reason why I need this separate application is third-party control that is available only for .NET Framework desktop - WinForms and WPF (unfortunatelly I cannot avoid using or replace it).

Is it possible to run that client PC application **inside** ASP Net Core HTML page?
I don't need just launch it with System.Diagnostics.Process or similar techniques, I want I want to embed it in a ASP frame somehow. Something like WindowsFormsHost for WFP or ElementHost for WinForms.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, otherwise companies would never bothered to migrate their desktop app to web and just adopt that route. Such thing might be possible in the olden days of ActiveX and IE. Generally today you'll write an API in .NET Core that answers your WinForm requests

Comment: Well I suppose one can run it on server then stream the screen just like all those game streaming services that run on browser.

Comment: @Martheen sad to hear that.. Thank you for explanation. P.S.Streaming the screen with user feedback would be much more difficult to implement that a simple Web API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have these options:

- Wrap your desktop app into ActiveX, use [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) extension (or similar one), and run ActiveX on the page. The worst one because of, well, ActiveX. In fact, you will not be able to use modern browser features.
- Throw away Web UI. If you need desktop app (it doesn't matter *why*), then use desktop app and Web API at server side. The easiest and obvious one. You're still linked to desktop, so what is the reason to ignore this fact?
- Render mentioned control's output at server side, and send the result to browser. This depends on what the control is, what it does, how much interactivity it requires, etc. Also, this assumes, that you must be able to run .NET 4.8 process on your server and communicate with it from .NET Core app.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I need to go desktop app + Web API way..